# Cannot Do BULK INSERT or cannot run BCP OpenRowSet from CSV File?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert, bcp

I have data in the data CSV File. I am trying to insert data from this csv data file into SQL Server Database Table.

I tried the below 2 options. Nothing is working for me.
1. BULK INSERT
2.BCP OPENROWSET

For Bulk Insert I am getting this below Error.

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\ATACLS001PVFS\userdata$\haritha.pinninty\work\Test\Test.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
```

For BCP OpenRowSet, I am getting below Error.

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.
```

How to resolve these issues?
I am executing these Queries/Stored procedures from the SQL Server Query Analyser where i logged on using Windows Authentication.

I did not have Admin Priveleges on the machine yet.

Apprecaite your responses.

Thanks
Rita

Answer (score 0):

Error message says it all,you need to download ACE Provider using below link.please note that this should be installed on machine where you are trying to import

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

***You need admin Permissions to install***

Answer (score 0):

"For Bulk Insert I am getting this below Error."

Did you have the file open (i.e. Excel)?  If so, close it from your desktop application.

Comment: No. I don't have file open.

Comment: Apologies for the dumb question, but I had to ask.